# What advantages does it bring to use C# event system to implement Publisher/Subscriber pattern instead of implementing it with class interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

There is an implementation shown here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx

What's the advantages over just implementing this design pattern the classical way with class interfaces ?

For example where is the decoupling since you have tight direct binding between the subscribers and the publisher through the instruction:

```
pub.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
```

So that in this case I can't see any decoupling advantage over direct classical implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convenience is a biggie, especially since C# doesn't have the inner classes of Java; since it would be a single-method interface, this allows trivial subscription - perhaps via a method on the type, but perhaps even inline:

```
pub.RaiseCustomEvent += delegate { DoSomething(); };
```

The above also allows for full lexical capture of any variables etc (contrast with Java, which captures the *values* of any variables - not the variables themselves - so 2-way communication is possible).

To do this with an interface I would need to declare a new class, implement the interface, provide a method to provied the implementation, and handle any variable/capture transfer.

Events *also* allow broadcast to multiple subscribers in a very convenient way.

Delegates are also easier to create at runtime (for meta-programming etc) than classes are - for example I can create a delegate (from scratch) at runtime and subscribe it pretty easily, using either `DynamicMethod` (if I fancy IL) or `Expression` (if I fancy AST). To create a type and implement an interface is a bit more work (`AssemblyName`, `AssemblyBuilder`, `ModuleBuilder`, `TypeBuilder` and at least 2 `Type`s and `MethodInfo`s).

Comment: Thanks for the idea of Dynamic Method and Expression (though I don't know what you mean by AST :))

Comment: Now I don't find event system so convenient there are a bunch of declarations with bloggling heavy syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

Again, convenience:

With interfaces, you have to:

- derive from interface
- implement callbacks (all of them!), even if you don't need some event
- register

With events, everything is done in one line, and .NET automatically handles multiple hooks to one event.